# Can anyone suggest any free alternative to clamav for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, antivirus, siem

My Alien Vault SIEM is showing some vulnerabilities based on on the connection this server is making, I tried to use clamav with the vulnerability hashes provided by SIEM (along with it's original definitions). Can someone suggest me any other on-demand scanner tool which can be operated using CLI commands for this purpose?